# Figure caption under \photo{} in moderncv

Tags: graphics, captions, moderncv

I would like to get a figure caption under the photo included via the `\photo{}` command in a modercv template.

Normally, I would add figure captions like this in Latex:

```
\begin{figure}
    \caption{My caption}
    \includegraphics{MyPhoto}
\end{figure}
```

However, this obviously doesn't work in moderncv, as you can't place the `\photo{}` command in a figure environment.

Can anybody point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the internal code of `moderncv` to add a text to the photo. Changing internal code can be done using the `etoolbox` package, which offers a command `\patchcmd` with five arguments. The first argument is the name of the command that you want to modify, the second argument is the part of the command that you want to replace, the third argument is the replacement text that will be inserted at the position of the second argument (if that is found), and the fourth and fifth argument are executed when the replacement is successful or not, respectively (these can be left empty).

In this case you can replace the code that displays the photo with the same code with added text. The photo is placed inside of a `\framebox`, which does not allow line breaks, so you should also add an extra `\parbox` inside of the `\framebox` to get the caption on a new line.

Finally, because the code contains `@` symbols, you should surround the patching code with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}
% search for this code
{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}
% replace with this code
{\framebox{\parbox{\@photowidth}{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}\newline\centering This is me}}}
% fourth and fifth argument empty
{}{}
\makeatother
\name{Short}{LongName}
\email{asdf@gmail.com}
\phone[mobile]{+1123456789}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\photo{example-grid-100x100bp}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]